# Shorting a Superconducting Coil with A/C

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields, superconductivity, power

When a superconducting coil carrying a direct current is shorted, it continues to carry the current without loss (approximately), assuming it stays cooled and superconducting.

What would happen if the coil were carrying AC, then shorted?  Would the AC current persist as is, just like it would with DC?  Would the frequency make a difference? (Specifically interested in high frequency, khz+)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A superconducting coil acts mostly as a perfect inductor, so it resists current variations. If it is plugged to an AC voltage source, it will pass an AC current corresponding to its inductance.

When shorted, it will continue running the current that was running through it just before shorting (as $V=0=L di/dt$). So you're going to end up with a constant current, that can be anywhere between the extreme values of the AC current that was running before the short.

On a more general note, remember that AC analysis only works with stationnary AC signals. With transients, you need to resort to time domain analysis.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.  Makes sense.  I'm curious, are there any additional difficulties with high frequency AC in a superconducting circuit as opposed to a traditional copper cicuit? (ignoring transients)  I guess I'm wondering why some of the big 10+ Tesla superconducting electromagnets don't run a few experiments with AC.

Comment: And the objective will be? If you are talking of LHC magnets, they need the magnetic field to be constant to define the beams and the tracks in the detectors.